# Keywords Planner in Google Ads API

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to use Keywords Planner programmatically, through its API.I came across [Generating Targeting Ideas](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service), which pretty much summarizes the use. When I visit [Get Started](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/start), it states

> Try the new Google Ads API—which has the latest Google Ads features. The AdWords API is in maintenance mode and not being actively developed.

I visit [Google Ads API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start), where I cannot find anything related to the Keyword Planner.

Has someone any idea if the planner is available through the new API, or do I have to use the old one?

Thanks,

Alexios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently working on converting an old Adwords cron job to the new Ads API. While I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, the old `TargetingIdeaService` has been replaced with a new `KeywordPlanIdeaService` (see https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/migration/services).

You can find examples for KeywordPlanIdeaService here:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/generate-keyword-ideas

Pay careful attention to how the code formats each selector field and using a helper class to format language and geotargeting codes. It's not the most intuitive way of passing paramters.

Comment: can zou please help me with google ads api, i'm using this but seem that i have some problem. My code stop } catch (GoogleAdsException $googleAdsException) {
            printf( .I got this error : ApiException was thrown with message '{
    "message": "Operation is not implemented, or supported, or enabled.",
    "code": 12,
    "status": "UNIMPLEMENTED",
    "details": []